# Development of monopoly game

Tags: java

I seem to have a problem with a subtask. It's in danish so I put in the translated version of it:

> - Create a class `Field`, that is representing the fields of a monopoly game. Initially, `Field` can contain these encapsulated variables:
>
>   - `String name` -  short name of the field
>   - `int number` - a number in the range[1..40]
>
> Both variables must be initialized in a constructor, and there must only be getters, as they never will be changed after creation.
>   Moreover, there should be a method with the signature `public String toString()`, so it's easy to print what `Field` a player has landed on. 
>   At first it's allowed to just call the fields Field1, Field2...

My Field class look like this:

```
public class Field {

    String name;
    int number;

    public Field(String name, int number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}
```

In my `main` method I wanted to test this. So I wrote the following:

```
Field[] board = new Field[40]; // a board containing 40 fields

for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    board[i] = new Field("Field" + (i + 1), i + 1);
}

System.out.println("Board: " + Arrays.toString(board));
```

In my console I get this:

> Board: [test.Field@2a139a55, test.Field@15db9742, test.Field@6d06d69c,......]

And I want this:

> Board: [Field1, Field2, Field3,......]

Answer (score 6):

Override `Field`'s `toString()` to return the name, i.e.

```
public String toString() {
  return name;
}
```

What you get (e.g. `test.Field@2a139a55`) is the default implementation of `toString()` which can be found in `Object`:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You missed the

> Moreover, there should be a method with the signatur public String toString(),

part of your task.

Comment: ... which is the way of saying "override `toString()`" without actually using the concept of overriding etc. - I guess polymorphism wasn't yet part of the OP's schedule ;)

Comment: Since it works now, you should accept @Thomas' answer (or mine, but his is way better).

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to use java8? Then I would suggest this:

```
Field[] board = new Field[40]; // a board containing 40 fields

for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
    board[i] = new Field("Field" + (i + 1), i + 1);
}

String commaSeparatedName =
    Arrays.stream(board) // all items as stream
          .map(Field::getName) // for each take its name
          .collect(Collectors.joining(", "); // join names with a comma
System.out.println("Board: [" + commaSeparatedNames +"]");
```